# Django models filter/get query

Tags: django, django-models

When I run the following line in my django code:

`Site.objects.filter(id='19282')`

I get the following:

`<Site: Chicago>`

Can someone please help me so that when I use "Site.objects.filter(id=received_post_data.get('19282')" I get just the value "Chicago" as a string ?

Comment: Share the `Site` model.

Answer (score 1):

Say your Site model has a "name" attribute. Define a `__str__` method for the Site model as follows.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

then after you filter just just surround it with `str()` or call the `__str__()` on the instance. Note though these are strictly different methods, but usually return the same thing.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Just wrapping the result around with str helped me to fix this. Since I already had the __str__ method.